# what is the utilization of data member in abstract class

Tags: java

Abstract classes in Java are classes which cannot be instantiated, meaning we cannot create new instances of an abstract class. The purpose of an abstract class is to function as a base for subclasses.
but why java allows to define data member in an *abstract class*, where we can not create object of an abstract class.

Comment: A protected variable can be useful/needed to make the methods function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an abstract class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912475/what-is-an-abstract-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you can have concrete classes which you can create instances of. Say you have the abstract class `Animal` - every animal has, say, a `Color` - so you keep it as a member of the base class, although you can't create a simple `Animal` (you could create a `Dog` or a `Cat` thought, but both have colors).

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes can be extended by other concrete classes.Those cocrete classes can use this data member.

Abstract classes are nothing but the classes which can not be instantiated but they may have some common logic and common member variables which all concrete classes should contain.

Answer (score 0):

we have Abstract class called Shape(Shape of : square,circle,rectangle)here Square, circle and rectangle are sub-classes which extends  Abstract Class Shape. Assume  we are calculating the area of the different shape where area (field/variable)  will be common to all the sub-classes.so,it can declare inside the Abstract class instead of declaring in each sub-classes.